# Need Linux cmd-line app to compare binary files and exit on 1st mis-match

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, binary, compare

Is there a Linux command-line app which will compare two binary files and exit on the first mis-match?

`cmp` doesn't seem to have the quit opition.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`cmp` doesn't have this *option*, because it always quits on the first mismatch.

```
$ cmp -b /bin/ls /bin/sed
/bin/ls /bin/sed differ: byte 25, line 1 is 320 M-P 300 M-@
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to Linux, so I'll use that as an excuse :) ...  I tried it with the -l option which ploughs on regardless.. I looked at (but didn't try) the -b option, becaues the man-page only said "Print differing bytes", with no mention of quitting...  Live and learn! ... Thanks..

Comment: The `-b` option is just there for illustration, if omitted the behavior is still what you want. Sadly, many of the standard utilities (the ones from GNU) have very poor manpages.

Answer (score 4):

I think you could go by using 3 tools:

- `cmp`
- `diff`
- `md5sum`

`cmp` is better for binary files and `diff` is better for text files
For binary files `diff` merely reports whether they differ ot not. `diff` works also for directories.

Any of the first two could accomplish what you need silently. `diff` uses the `-q` switch and  `cmp` uses the `-s` switch to tell you just a return code: 0 if the two files match 1 if not.

`cmp` has also a nice option to avoid (sort of) reading the entire file (good if you have big files): if you know that the files could differ in the first N lines or between line N and M you could do (i.e.: for row N = 10 and M = 20):

```
cmp file1 file2 10 20
```

I added `md5sum` to the list because if you have the chance to calculate the MD5 checksum every time you edit one of those files, then you could compare only that to quickly find if they match or not. In this case I assume that you have a lot of file to compare.

Comment: Thanks, but it wasn't so much the issue of *silent*, as it was about not chugging through 5 GB of data unnecessarily...

Comment: Again, thanks for the extra info.. I wanted this for a one-off compare of 2 DVD .iso's (and for future reference), so I was definitely after the quick-exit on mismatch... (Your extra effort in presenting a fuller answer gets you a mark from me :)