# Compare two folders and copy/link unique entries to a new folder

Tags: bash, scripting, set-operations

How can I copy all unique files from two source folders to a new destination folder?

As a set operation: How can I compute the difference between two folders?

Comment: (1) Is this recursive -- do you have a directory tree -- or are you just looking at the direct contents of each folder? (2) Can there be a file in one source folder with the same name as a file in the other, but with different contents? If so, are they considered distinct, or the same?

Comment: (1) Yes, recursive. (2) In my case, the content should not change (only new files added) but to make the answer more useful for more people, it would be great if it caught different content, too (also, my assumption might be wrong one day).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy all files from `foo/` and `bar/` to `baz/`, the simplest way is just to copy both, and let one overwrite the other:

```
cp --recursive foo/ baz/
cp --recursive bar/ baz/
```

If you want to be a bit cleaner, and *not* copy from `bar/` anything that exists in `foo/`, you could write:

```
cp --recursive foo/ baz/
( cd bar/
  find -exec bash -c ' if ! [[ -e ../foo/"{}" ]] ; then
                         cp "{}" ../baz/"{}"
                       fi
                     ' \;
)
```

You can use the same approach to generate a list of files in `bar/` that don't exist in `foo/`:

```
( cd bar/
  find -exec bash -c ' if ! [[ -e ../foo/"{}" ]] ; then
                         echo bar/"{}"
                       fi
                     ' \;
)
```

(or you could change `echo bar/"{}"` to `printf %s\0 bar/"{}"` to use a zero-valued byte, rather than a newline, as a separator).

Alternatively, for some variety, you could write:

```
diff --old-line-format=%L --new-line-format= --unchanged-line-format= \
     <( cd foo/ ; find | sort ) <( cd bar/ ; find | sort )
```

which passes the outputs of `cd foo/ ; find | sort` and `cd bar/ ; find | sort` to `diff` as the input-files, and tells `diff` to print the lines that are found *only* in the first input-file and discard everything else. (Note: this will break if any filenames contain newlines.)

None of the above compares the contents of the different files, simply because I'm not sure what should be done if they're different. Examining file-contents could use `diff -r -q foo/ bar/` as a starting-point, but what do we do with that?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
cd <First Dir>
find . > /tmp/first.dat
cd <Second Dir>
find . > /tmp/second.dat
comm -23 /tmp/first.dat /tmp/second.dat | while read line; do cp <First Dir>/$line <New Dir> ; done
comm -13 /tmp/first.dat /tmp/second.dat | while read line; do cp <SecondDir>/$line <New Dir> ; done
```

Comment: This extends nicely to the "file name exists, but with different contents" scenario. Instead of just two lists of file names, you can compare two lists of date stamp, file size, file name tuples, md5sums, or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are other ways (without the extra file operations suggested in here), but here is a relatively easy way to accomplish this.

Assumptions:
A1) Only interested in the direct contents of the folder.
A2) Files with the same name are assumed to have identical content.

1) create/use an empty temporary directory (tmp)
2) copy the contents of sourceDir1 to tmp
3) delete the contents of sourceDir2 from tmp
-- Now you have the unique files of sourceDir1 in tmp
4) move the contents of tmp into the desired location
5) repeat steps 2)-4) with the roles of sourceDir1 and sourceDir2 swapped

Notes:
N1) You can use `ls` to list files (or directories), and redirect it to a file (say s1.tmp).  Then you can compare the list of files (directories) of the other folder by using `grep` to see if the current file (directory) is listed in s1.tmp.  You can use this technique to calculate what directories to enter for recursive processing (thus relaxing A1)).
N2) If the files in question are text files, you can use diff to see if they are identical.  If yes, proceed as before, otherwise process the case of identical file name, different content appropriately (e.g. copy both files to the destination directory using unique extentions to indicate their source -- the logic here depends on your goal).
N3) You can compare binary files as well apparently, see [stackoverflow#4013223](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013223/need-linux-cmd-line-app-to-compare-binary-files-and-exit-on-1st-mis-match) and [superuser#135911](https://superuser.com/questions/135911/how-do-a-binary-diff-on-two-identically-sized-files-under-linux)

Answer (score 0):

At first, I thought I could solve this with clever usage of `rsync` but nothing really worked.

So my final solution was a small [Python script (gist)](https://gist.github.com/2157729).